# Find Max Value in string/integers in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column `UniqueID` of type varchar. This column has unique IDs labeled as follows:

```
DU19F0001
DU19M001
DU19M002
DU19F002
EL19F001
EL19F002
MU19M001
MU19M002
```

I am trying to select for the last max value based on this mixed string. For instance what is the last value for 'DU' '19' 'F'? The result should then be `DU19F002`. How do I write a query for selecting the max value based on a mix of strings and integers in a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select max(uniqueid)
from t
where uniqueid like 'DU19F%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for the first 5 (or whatever) characters, you can do this:

```
select
first_part,
max(uniqueid)
from
(
select substring(uniqueid,1,5) as first_part,uniqueid from <your table> ) t
group by first_part
```